# Django/Python - Cannot assign "1": "Company.merchant" must be a "Merchant" instance

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

**couldn't figure out a way to give self.companies.merchant a id**

***error is :  Cannot assign "1": "Company.merchant" must be a "Merchant" instance.***

I looked for another questions like this but didn't understand.

```
   self.merchant = Merchant.objects.create(
        name='merchant',
        ref_code='45664',
    )

    self.companies = Company.objects.create(
        name='companyone',
        ref_code='222',
        merchant=Merchant.objects.first().id,
    ),
    self.merchant.companies.add(*self.companies)
```

Merchant model:

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Company Model :

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(
       'accounts.Merchant', related_name='companies')
```

Comment: Unrelated, but if you create the companies with the Merchant instance (or merchant_id) already set, you don't need the call to `merchant.companies.add(...)` - the companies are _already_ linked to the merchant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide either `Merchant` instance(to `merchant` argument) or `id` but assign it to `merchant_id` argument. So this will work:

```
self.companies = Company.objects.create(
        name='companyone',
        ref_code='222',
        merchant_id=Merchant.objects.first().id,
    ),
```

Or

```
self.companies = Company.objects.create(
        name='companyone',
        ref_code='222',
        merchant=Merchant.objects.first(),
    ),
```

Also you would get `TypeError`, because you are trying to unpack `self.companies` which is `Company` instance and not iterable.
And as @brunodesthuilliers noted, merchant would be already connected to created `Company` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.companies = Company.objects.create(
    name='companyone',
    ref_code='222',
    merchant_id=Merchant.objects.first().id,
)
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer